# How to avoid repetitive conditions in authorization policies in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, policy, asp.net-core-7.0

I have policy based security on my controllers, working as expected. One thing that bothers me, is the repetition of certain conditions in the policy definitions. It bothers me even extra more since I consider those conditions rather obvious if not necessary and implied.

```
options.AddPolicy("policy_01", builder =>
{
  builder.AddAuthenticationSchemes(Constants.Scheme);
  builder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
  builder.RequireClaim("client_claim01", "value01");
});
...
options.AddPolicy("policy_99", builder =>
{
  builder.AddAuthenticationSchemes(Constants.Scheme);
  builder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
  builder.RequireClaim("client_claim99", "value99");
});
```

So I have 99 problems but compactness ain't one...

Is there a way to omit the requirement that the user is authenticated (du'h) and that the schema applied is *Bearer* (sort of du'h)?

NB. I'm not looking on reconstructing the individual policies. I only wonder if there's a way I'm not aware of to implicitly set that for every and each policy.

The best I could think of is to add extension method on the `AuthorizationPolicyBuilder` class and put those as a first step, then managing the actual, policy-specific, requirement. However, it seems hacky and shaky, so I sense there's a much better approach.

Comment: You could create a custom `IAuthorizationPolicyProvider`, that validates your base line policies like `policy_01` and then all additionally provided policies - or if it can't resolve the policies falls back to the `DefaultAuthorizationPolicyProvider`, which then takes over. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-7.0
This way you could create a base line policy, that gets evaluated globally and can offload the rest into bespoke policy definitions.

Comment: Could you store your claims & policies in a lookup/dictionary, the iterate over so you only write it once?

Comment: @Marco Would you post that as a reply? That makes for a good answer in my opinion. Also the one by *itsdaniel0* might be a quickier version (not really fully pro-pro but nice to see).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an easier way then to create a custom `IAuthorizationPolicyProvider`.

Option 1 is to use the Combine method of [`AuthorizationPolicyBuilder`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/bec278eabea54f63da15e10e654bdfa4168a2479/src/Security/Authorization/Core/src/AuthorizationPolicyBuilder.cs#L88)

```
var basePolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
    .RequireClaim("client_claim01", "value01")
    .Build();

var mySecondPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
    .Combine(basePolicy)
    .RequireClaim("client_claim99", "value99")
    .Build();
```

`AuthorizationPolicyBuilder` even has a [constructor](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/bec278eabea54f63da15e10e654bdfa4168a2479/src/Security/Authorization/Core/src/AuthorizationPolicyBuilder.cs#L33) that automatically calls `Combine`:

```
var mySecondPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(basePolicy)
    .RequireClaim("client_claim99", "value99")
    .Build();
```

Option 2: Create a custom Builder that automatically adds your baseline requirements:

```
public class MyAuthorizationPolicyBuilder : AuthorizationPolicyBuilder
{
    public MyAuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
    {
        this.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        this.RequireClaim("Foo");
    }
}


options.AddPolicy("policy_99", new MyAuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
  .RequireClaim("client_claim99", "value99");
  .Build());
```

And if you wanted to test this approach:

```
[Fact]
public void Each_Policy_Should_Require_Authenticated_User()
{
    var builder = new MyAuthorizationPolicyBuilder();
    var policy = builder.Build();
    Assert.True(policy.Requirements.Any(x => x is DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement));
}
```